# How would I autofill the x509 certificate generation openssl prompts/pass in a file with answers to the certificate generation prompts?

Tags: bash, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, x509

I made an openssl script that generates an ssl certificate. Looks something like this:

```
...
openssl req -new -sha256 -key privkey.key -out cert.csr
...
```

Where 'privkey.key' is the private key I generated for the certificate. So when I run the script, when it executes the line

> openssl req -new -sha256 -key privkey.key -out cert.csr

It prompts the user to enter different info, such as Country Code, State/Province, etc.:
[image]

My question is, how would I create some kind of a 'request' file, that would contain answers to all those prompts and autofill them when the user runs this script (so that the user doesn't have to be prompted for anything)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: One option is to use the `-subj` option to `openssl req`.  See the [Using the -subj Switch](https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/openssl-quick-reference-guide.htm#Usingthe-subjSwitch) section in the [OpenSSL Quick Reference Guide | DigiCert.com](https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/openssl-quick-reference-guide.htm).

Comment: check this https://superuser.com/a/226229